# MATLAB using ode45 to animate wave function throws tolerance error

Tags: matlab, ode, numerical-integration

I am working on animating a wave function in MATLAB. So far, I have not reached to part of the animation yet since my ode45 throws an error. I am using de Korteweg-de Vries equations for this 
(which can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation).

Now my code is as follows:

```
function[t, N, u] = wave(u0, L, T, S, N)

%First we create a vector t which stores the time entries, a vector x which
%stores the location entries and an h which is the location step size for
%the Korteweg-De Vries function.
time = linspace(0,T,S);
x = linspace(-L,L,N);
h = x(2)-x(1);

U0=u0(x);

options=odeset('RelTol',1e-13,'AbsTol',1e-13);
[t,u] = ode45(@kdv,time,U0,options);

    function dudt = kdv(t,u)

    d2udx2 = ([u(N)-2*u(1)+u(2); diff(u,2); u(N-1)-2*u(N)+u(1)] ./ h^2);
    total = d2udx2 + 3.*u.^2;

    diff_total = diff(total);
    diff_total = [diff_total(end); diff_total(1:end)];

    dudt = -[diff_total(2)-diff_total(N-1); diff(diff_total,2); diff_total(N-1)+diff_total(2)] ./ (2*h);

    end
end
```

Now when I set `f=@(x)(2/2).*(1./cosh(sqrt(2).*x./2).^2)` and then call the function with `[t,N,u]=wave(f, 20, 10, 200, 200);` I get the following error:

> Warning: Failure at t=6.520003e-02.  Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below the
>   smallest value allowed (2.220446e-16) at time t. 
>   In ode45 (line 360)
>     In wave (line 23)

Also the returned `t` and `u` have a size of `16x1` and `16x200` respectively, but I think they would expand to `200x1` and `200x200` if the warning did not occur.

Any hints on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the reason to increase the iterated differences to order 5 with `diff_total`? Why is there a second order difference in the final derivative vector? Why do you not make the iterated differences into proper difference quotients by dividing with the appropriate power of `h`?

Comment: The Korteweg-de vries equations states du/dt = -d/dx * (d^2u/dx^2 + 3 u^2). I therefore think I need the second order difference, to get that part between the brackets, right?

Comment: Forget my last sentence, the proper divisions are there. `d2udx2` and thus `total` are constructed correctly. Moving additional remarks to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did too much differences, the middle step of constructing `diff_total` is redundant.

- `d2udx2` and thus `total` are constructed correctly. You could shorten the first construction as

  ```
  d2udx2 = diff([u(N);  u;  u(1) ], 2)./h^2`;
  ```
- The next step constructing `diff_total` is redundant with the difference construction in `dudt`. The `diff_total` construction is lacking a division by `h`, for some unknown reason you have difference order 2 in the middle of `dudt`.
- The outer `x` differentiation would be best done via convolution to get a central difference quotient as you have in the outer elements,

  ```
  dudt = -conv([ total(N); total; total(1)], [1; 0; -1], 'valid')/(2*h)
  ```

All together this gives the derivatives procedure

```matlab
function dudt = kdv(t,u,h)
    d2udx2 = diff([u(end);  u;  u(1) ], 2)./h^2;
    total = d2udx2 + 3*u.^2;
    dudt = -conv( [ total(end); total; total(1)], [1; 0; -1], 'valid')./(2*h);
end
```

which (with `N=80`) produces the solution

[image]

which as intended is a soliton wave traveling with speed `c=2`.